# Ruby on Rails : How to make a link for download database under json type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think my title is simple and tell all I need. It contains two parts :

```
a. Convert database to json. I can do this part now.
b. Make download link, and download json I have recent created.
```

I cannot do part b. I meet two problems :

> 1. How can make this link outside of the world ? I have make a file, for example "page.html.erb" into view folder, but when I type:
>      "localhost/Group/page" I will receive "routing error".
> 2. How can we do, when user type this link, browser will automatically download a file that I have generated above.

I'm a very new comer to Ruby on Rails, so those problems aren't not obvious to me. I have google some, but no real tutorial help me this. Please tell me how.

Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your question. When you say download, do you mean that you want to return json for a particular controller action?

Comment: "Download" means : for example, a user types a link into browser and it will download something into computer as we often see. Hope this make my statement clearer, thanks :)

Comment: @John often, when client get data from server, server return a html file. now, I want it return a json file. I think  I should do something with route.rb, but really don't know how to :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example Rails action that responds to json

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with @users
  end
end
```

you could then type the route in your browser /users in this case and append .json so /user.json will show all users in json.

You can make something json by simplly saying .to_json. Example: @user.to_json. This works for simple cases, but if you have a complex need then you should look into https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: thanks for `respond_to` I have google and understand it now :D